# SVG auto scale height

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to create circles using svg, and I'm struggling to make the SVG's height relative to the content. I know I could just hardset the width and height, but then the circles wouldn't be as close to each other. Height auto and width 100% doesn't seem to work when applying on SVG, here's my current HTML and css. I'm posting to see if anyone has a solution that I'm not aware of, I've been trying multiple combinations from other posts and nothing seems to get it done. Thank you in advance.

```
<div>
        <svg>
            <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="120" stroke-width="5" fill="Blue"></circle>
        </svg>
        
        <svg>
            <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="100" stroke-width="5" fill="Blue"></circle>
        </svg>
</div>


body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
        
body {
    background-color: Yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Problem: Circles get clipped because SVG has preset height's and width's that I can not figure out how to make relative to the content required.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, note that in HTML, any replaced element like:

- `<img>`
- `<svg>`
- `<canvas>` etc.

has a **default size** of `300px` wide, `150px` tall.

If you don't give the replaced element explicit dimensions, these are the dimensions it will adopt.

---

The tool that you are looking for is the **SVG viewBox**.

If you declare a `viewBox` for an SVG, this is like giving it its own set of *relative-to-self* dimensions.

These *relative-to-self* dimensions are separate from what's going on, on the rest of the page and, importantly, they are also separate from its *relative-to-context* dimensions.

In the example below, I have given the first `<svg>` the following `viewBox`:

```
viewBox="0 0 240 240"
```

this means that if it has a `<circle>` child element with a radius of `120`, then the circle will, essentially, fill the `<svg>`.

But if I change the `viewBox` to:

```
viewBox="0 0 480 480" // (ie. twice the size)
```

then the `<circle>` will now only fill half the `<svg>`.

And you can keep changing the size of the circle by changing the `viewBox` of the parent SVG ***even when*** (this is the clever bit) the relative-to-context dimensions of the `<svg>` remain:

- `width: 100px;`
- `height: 100px;`

or however large or small you want the `<svg>` to be on the page.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

svg:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 240px;
}

svg:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 200px;
}

svg circle {
  fill: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<div>
<svg viewBox="0 0 240 240">
<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="120" stroke-width="5"></circle>
</svg>
        
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="100" stroke-width="5"></circle>
</svg>
</div>
```